# How to show the total increment of an app counter

Tags: javascript, html, function, buttonclick

Guys I wanna make an app which can count people, I have it according to the course but I'd like to add the total at the end not the previous entries.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2D54l.png)

```
let saveEl = document.getElementById("save-el")
let countEl = document.getElementById("count-el")

let count = 0

function counter() {

    count += 1
    countEl.textContent = count

}

function save()   {

    //let countStr = count + "-" caso eu não queira que volte do zero

    let countStr = count + " - "

    saveEl.textContent += countStr 

    countEl.textContent = 0

    count = 0

}



console.log(count)
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that allows to reproduce the issue, as well as a clear description of what you are trying to achieve and what doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instructions were not clear but I guess you want to "sum up the counts" instead of displaying them separately.

Here's a codepen achieving that, hopefully that works for you ;)

```js
let saveEl = document.getElementById("save-el")
let countEl = document.getElementById("count-el")

let count = 0

function counter() {
    count += 1
    countEl.textContent = count
}

function save() {
    let prevCount = saveEl.textContent ? parseInt(saveEl.textContent) : 0
    saveEl.textContent = count + prevCount

    countEl.textContent = 0
    count = 0
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Counter</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Members :</h1>
  <button onClick=counter()>counter</button>
  <button onClick=save()>save</button>
  <p id="count-el"></p>
  <hr/>
  <p id="save-el"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: sorry guys if I wasn't so clear, that was my first post, thank you so much, it worked perfectly.